# My code is not updating correctly my page

Tags: javascript

I have two divs, one with display:none and the other with display:block.

When I click the button, I invert the div's displays and call the window.reload method.

Unfortunately it updates but it is a blank page and does not come out of it. What am I doing wrong?

MY code JS :

```
function showHistorico(){

  window.location.reload();
 tabPrincipal.style.display="none";
tabHistorico.style.display="block";

}
```

My HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" id="btnHistorico" onclick="showHistorico()">HISTÓRICO</button>

 <table class="table table-dark table-hover" id="tabPrincipal"> ... </table>
 <table class="table table-dark table-hover" id="tabHistorico" style="display:none"> ... </table>
```

Unfortunately it updates but it is a blank page and does not come out of it. What am I doing wrong?

MY code JS :

```
function showHistorico(){

  window.location.reload();
 tabPrincipal.style.display="none";
tabHistorico.style.display="block";

}
```

My HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" id="btnHistorico" onclick="showHistorico()">HISTÓRICO</button>

 <table class="table table-dark table-hover" id="tabPrincipal"> ... </table>
 <table class="table table-dark table-hover" id="tabHistorico" style="display:none"> ... </table>
```

EDIT

This is the loop code that runs on the table div Principal when it is shown:

```html
<td><i class="bi bi-printer-fill iconPrint"><span id="spanPrint">   SELECIONE PRA IMPRIMIR</span></i></td>
               
                <? for(var j=0; j < vistorias[i].length; j++) { ?>
                    <th><?= vistorias[i][j] ?></th>
                <? } ?>                
              </tr>
```

and this loop code executes when the div Historico is shown:

```html
 <td><i class="bi bi-printer-fill iconPrint"><span id="spanPrint">   SELECIONE PRA IMPRIMIR</span></i></td>
               
                <? for(var j=0; j < historico[i].length; j++) { ?>
                    <th><?= historico[i][j] ?></th>
                <? } ?>                
              </tr>
```

So I need the page to be reloaded. Because just calling the method which updates the arrays is not working

Comment: dude....is not gonna change anything if you place a `window.location.reload();` in there. it will reload the page right there and it won't read the rest of the code that comes after that line. Whats the point of reloading your page anyway? is there a special reason? or you think you need to reload in order to see your changes? cuz if that is the case, the reload is completely unnecesary

Comment: All `showHistorico()` effectively does is reload the page.  Nothing more.  Any expectation that it does more than that is simply an incorrect expectation.

Comment: also, I don't see anywhere in your code, where are you defining your variables `tabPrincipal` and `tabHistorico`. I'm assuming you used `getElementById` somewhere in your code that you just didn't share

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. But answering... The code is very extensive and that's why I just put it in a summarized way. The variables have actually already been declared as "getElementById". The intention of this reload is that in these divs there is a loop that fetches data from a google spreadsheet. And I need that every time the divs are changed, this loop happens so that the value of the tables is dynamically updated. This because there is a logic that removes data from a table and passes it to another

Comment: @CondomnioMultiempresarial: That's all well and good, but it doesn't change what's clearly happening in the code shown.  The page is explicitly being reloaded.  So any expectation of those next to lines of code actually doing anything is an incorrect expectation.  There's no guarantee that those two lines of code (the ones updating the style info) will execute at all, because the page is being reloaded.  And even if they do execute, their changes are a moot point, because the page is being reloaded.  It's not really clear what else you're trying to describe, but it isn't part of the question.

Comment: I commented as an answer below

Answer (score 1):

I found a way. I created a variable and assigned a button to it. Then I created a hidden div(divAny) with display none and after the logic of my page is executed, the divAny is displayed passing the created variable in the innerHTML attribute. Now it's working as I want.

Button Code:

```js
var btnAtualizar = '<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="atualizaLista()" style="cursor:pointer;border:none"><b><font color="white" size="2px">VOLTAR</font></b></button>';
```

Code divAny:

```js
rodapeMsgBox.innerHTML=btnAtualizar;
```

Code executed in onclick function:

```js
function atualizaLista(){
  window.open(menuListaVistoria,"_top");
  showMsgBox("PROCESSANDO...");
}
```

Remembering that all variables in my code are already declared

Answer (score 0):

Define your variables first.

No need to reload the page, as I mentioned in the comments. If you reload then the rest of the code won't execute.

```js
const tabPrincipal = document.getElementById("tabPrincipal");
const tabHistorico = document.getElementById("tabHistorico");

function showHistorico() {

  //window.location.reload();
  tabPrincipal.style.display = "none";
  tabHistorico.style.display = "block";

}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" id="btnHistorico" onclick="showHistorico()">HISTÓRICO</button>
<br>
<table class="table table-dark table-hover" id="tabPrincipal">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>table principal header</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>table principal body</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table class="table table-dark table-hover" id="tabHistorico" style="display:none;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>table historico header</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>table historico body</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the explanations are given in comments. If you have any question feel free to ask.

```html
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" id="btnHistorico" onclick="showHistorico()">HISTÓRICO</button>

<!-- display: none; can't hide unless you write anything within the proper table structure like below -->
<table class="table table-dark table-hover" id="tabPrincipal"><tr><td>...tabPrincipal</td></tr></table>
<table class="table table-dark table-hover" id="tabHistorico" style="display: none;"><tr><td>...tabHistorico</td></tr></table>

<script>
  // You need to grab the elements first
  var tabPrincipal = document.querySelector('#tabPrincipal');
  var tabHistorico = document.querySelector('#tabHistorico');

  function showHistorico(){
    // This is just a page refresh which I believe is not necessary here (so hiding it)
    // window.location.reload();
    tabPrincipal.style.display= "none";
    tabHistorico.style.display= "block";
  }
</script>
```